# Convert multiple records into single record in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
user_id  channel user_type      score  user_band 
user1      0     Primary         577       A         
user1      0     Secondary       574       B    
user1      2     primary         500       c
user2.     0     primary         400       A
```

I am trying to convert multiple records into single record based on below conditions

1. For every distinct "user_id" and channel=0 ,select the record with "user_type" = primary record and replace the values of "score" and "user_band" with values of "user_type" = secondary.

Expected output

```
user_id  channel user_type      score  user_band 
user1      0     Primary         574       B            
user1      2     primary         500       c
user2      0     primary         400       A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
create table yourtable (user_id varchar(50), channel int, user_type varchar(50), score int, user_band varchar(10));
insert into yourtable values('user1',0,     'Primary',         577,'A');         
insert into yourtable values('user1',0,     'Secondary',       574,'B');    
insert into yourtable values('user1',2,     'primary',         500,'c');
insert into yourtable values('user2',0,     'primary',         400,'A');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with cte as
( 
  select *,row_number()over(partition by user_id,channel order by user_type)rn,
  lead(score)over(partition by user_id,channel order by user_type)lead_score,
  lead(user_band)over(partition by user_id,channel order by user_type)lead_user_band
  from yourtable
)
select user_id,channel,user_type, coalesce(lead_score,score) score, coalesce(lead_user_band,user_band) user_band from cte where rn=1;
```

| user_id | channel | user_type | score | user_band |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 0 | Primary | 574 | B |
| user1 | 2 | primary | 500 | c |
| user2 | 0 | primary | 400 | A |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)